# How to reset the id sequence of a Postgresql table on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table 'entreprises' in my database which I filled by manually loading data using a thirds party application. As a result the id sequence is a all messed up and I get id=null error message when trying to create new records.

Heroku support recommended me to use: `heroku pg:psql -a app_name`, and go from there.

but I am not sure how to proceed from there actually. I tried : `pg_set_serial_sequence('entreprises','id')` but get an error as well: No Function Matches the given name and argument types....

I don t think it is a difficult task, not sure why Heroku support did not provide the full solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just log in to Postgres server or connect your database with `pgadmin` or any other Postgres GUI tool and run the following command in the query window.

```
truncate table entreprises restart identity
```

**This will delete all the records from your table.**

Comment: hey is this going to delete all the table ?

Comment: yes, this deletes all the records from the table and reset the id count to zero.

Comment: Damn...18,000 records at risk. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect to heroku console

   ```
   heroku run rails c -app app_name
   ```
2. Run the following code

   ```
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!('entreprises')
   ```

Comment: Hey, this returns "nil" is itnormal ? I thought it would return the last id or something

Comment: @FrankyDoul Yes, it should return the last id

Comment: @FrankyDoul Is there any record which id is nil?

Comment: I just checked, no, there is no record with nil

Comment: @FrankyDoul run `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables` command in console and check the table name

Comment: i just checked the table name as you suggested, the table is there and the name is correct.

Comment: irb(main):007:0> Entreprise.first.company_name
  Entreprise Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "entreprises".* FROM "entreprises" ORDER BY "entreprises"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> "Li & Fung"

Comment: @FrankyDoul Did you do this query in local or heroku?

Comment: This is on Heroku, via heroku run rails c -app app_name

Comment: @FrankyDoul It should work. I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201844/discussion-between-franky-doul-and-demir).

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions worked for me, especially not the one that could make me delete the entire table. I chose a different approach, which is passing all the table into `UUID` and save the old_id into a different table:

```
class ResetIdOfEntreprise < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :entreprises, :uuid, :uuid, default: "uuid_generate_v4()", null: false
    add_column :entreprises, :old_id, :integer
    Entreprise.update_all("old_id=id")

    change_table :entreprises do |t|
      t.remove :id
      t.rename :uuid, :id
    end
    execute "ALTER TABLE entreprises ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);"
  end
end
```